# MS Excel - Extract Unique Text Patterns Keyword from Substring

Tags: excel, pattern-matching, extract, wildcard

I would like through the use of a MS Excel Formula to extract text/year from a substring of text containing a unique search pattern.  I have a column (Cell A2:A19) of unique dates, in some instances there is surrounding text before and after the text, that I would like to extract only the year that all uniquely begin with the number "1" (i.e., 17??, 18??, 19??, etc.)

Current Formula
[image]

```
DATE    
April 1 1799    
April 11 1867    
February 12 1806    
February 21 1798    
February 28 1844 as Delaware Township    
February 5 1798    
February 7 1892 Verona Township    
February 9 1797    
January 19 1748    
July 10 1721 as Upper Penns Neck Township    
March 15 1860    
March 17 1870 (as Raritan Township)    
March 17 1874    
March 23 1864    
March 5 1867    
April 28th 1828    
1840s    
1878 as Lehigh Township
```

CURRENT RESULTS (from formula used above)

[image]

[image]

DESIRABLE RESULTS:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you put the data as text in the Original post so we do not need to re-type what is already typed just to test our formulas.

Comment: Put it in your original post not the comments as the comments cannot be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will get you every one except the `1840s`

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"17?? ","18?? ","19?? "},A2 & " "),1E+99)),4))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter on exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott, it works and as you kindly indicated with the minor exception, which I can totally live with, thank you, your provided formula works fantastic... THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

If macros are allowed you can create a code module and put this code in it:

```
Public Function GetYear(text As String)
    Dim regex
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = ".*(\d{4}).*"
    Set matches = regex.Execute(text)

    GetYear = matches(0).Submatches(0)
End Function
```

Then, you can use a formula like "=GetYear(A1)" to get all years, including 1840s and other similar formats. It basically searches for a group of four digits next to each other in the given string. Not the best date matching algorithm, but sounds like it'll be enough for your use case.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the provided Macro, as I will use this method as a much needed alternative opposed to Formulas.  I was also able to achieve the desired results using Scott's formula with only a minor modification... Thanks Again..

Answer (score 0):

Using the MS Excel formula provided by Scott, I was able to make a minor tweek that resolved the issue of also capturing/extracting only dates and other similar.  This was achieved by only adding the wildcard Asterisk symbol to represent any series of characters, following the question marks "??".  Thanks Scott...      =IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({"16??* ","17??* ","18??* ","19??* "},A2 & " "),1E+99)),4)),"")

Comment: You will get false positives with this.  Look at the return for `January 19 1748` it will return `19 1` because it finds the day first.  That is the reason that I did what I did.  Mine will at least narrow down the few that you will need to do manually.

Comment: Scott, you are correct... I did experience what you've indicated, thus, I reverted to your provided formula.  Thanks..